# How to make variables in one function visible to other functions

Tags: c, scope

Say I have something along the lines of

```
void init(void){
    int foo = 0;
}
void useFoo(void){
    foo++;
}
void main{
    init();
    useFoo();
}
```

Where we have an init function that initializes one (or more) variables, and then another function (or, potentially, multiple functions) that have to use that variable, how do I make "int foo" visible to those other functions?

Comment: That would be what *function-parameters* are for, or did I completely fly off the radar? And that variable belongs in `main()`; not `init()`

Answer (score 2):

You can make it visible on global scope:

```
int foo;

void init()
{
    foo = 0;
}

void useFoo()
{
    ++foo;
}
```

Also you can pass a pointer to variable where it is needed:

```
void init(int *foo)
{
    *foo = 0;
}

void useFoo(int *foo)
{
    (*foo)++;
}

...
int foo;
init(&foo);
useFoo(&foo);
```

Or you can use thread-local storage, files, other media, but I believe you don't want that :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "you can't" (at least not that way).  The variable `foo` in `init` is created at entry to `init`, then destroyed on return from `init`.  It no longer exists by the call to `useFoo`.

You need the variable to have a longer "storage duration" (program-level lifetime).  You can do that by making it have "static duration" (via the `static` keyword and moving it outside of the function—although actually, moving it out suffices), in which case there is only once instance (a "singleton" in many other languages' taxonomies).  Alternatively, you can build a data structure that you create using `malloc`, giving the data "allocated duration": it lasts from the point of the `malloc` until a later `free` (we'll ignore `realloc` for now :-) ).

The allocated-duration method is more cumbersome but more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

the simplies way is making it a global variable:

```
int foo;
void init(void) {
    foo = 0;
}
void useFoo(void) {
    foo++;
}
void main(void) {
    init();
    useFoo();
}
```

Another way is by using the pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void init(int *foo) {
    *foo = 0;
}
void useFoo(int *foo) {
    (*foo)++;
}
void main(void) {
    int foo;
    init(&foo);
    useFoo(&foo);
    useFoo(&foo);
    useFoo(&foo);
    printf("%d\n", foo);
}
```

And the last one is passing it as a reference (when using CPP, not C):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void init(int &foo) {
    foo = 0;
}
void useFoo(int &foo) {
    foo++;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int foo;
    init(foo);
    useFoo(foo);
    useFoo(foo);
    useFoo(foo);
    printf("%d\n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```